# Help identifying I2C EEPROM - top marking H250 2GB 2

Tags: identification, i2c, repair, eeprom

I have a Fujitsu server (PRIMERGY RX300 S8) with a failed I2C EEPROM on the front panel PCB. I would like to order the correct replacement components, but I am unable to identify the exact series/capacity of the chips.

[image: I2C EEPROMs]

I believe the top EEPROM (D3) is an [STMicroelectronics 64Kbit EEPROM](https://forums.parallax.com/discussion/comment/1097208/#Comment_1097208), probably from the [M24C64](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/m24c64-f.pdf) series.

The bottom EEPROM (D2) is completely unknown to me, I can't seem to find anything from a search engine for "I2C EEPROM H250 2GB"

I am certain that D2 and D3 pictured are I2C EEPROMs in a TSSOP8 package, I just don't know the model numbers and I'm hoping someone here can identify them.

I am aware that I could purchase a complete front panel PCB from the vendor or eBay, but that is not my question.

Comment: You sure its not a RAM chip? Quick search I found this https://www.psaparts.co.uk/memory-laptop/fujitsu-siemens/celsius-mobile-h250-dimm--hqjmbc.html?_url=/storage/fujitsu-siemens/celsius-mobile-h250-dimm--hqjmbc.html

Comment: Why do you think it has failed?

Comment: @dka13 that's obiously not an IC

Comment: @KevinWhite The question is regarding chip identification, not troubleshooting. I would like to know the exact model so I can purchase replacements.

Comment: @dka13, your link points to an SoDIMM RAM module, a completely different component from the one in the image and also not in any way compatible with a Primergy RX300 Server.

Comment: @hwmartin - You said in the question it had failed. I wondered why you think so. It is extremely unusual for ICs to fail. Even more unusual is to purchase devices with the expectation they will fail in the future.

Comment: @KevinWhite Who cares? The question is about identifying ICs, not their reliability.

Comment: Picture quality isn't great, but what are those spots all over the board? Just flux residue or some manner of pollution?

Comment: Hey guys, may I ask what size is this and what's the name, I want an adapter for this but can't find it. The normal ones are called TSSOP8. Is there a list available of all sizes? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly a 2.5V serial EEPROM similar to [AT24C1024B](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc5194.pdf), made in the 50th week of 2012

[image]